# Blockly Python port

Tags: python, blockly

I want to add some functions to Blockly (programming language) such as save and load, which is a bit hard inside of a browser. I only need to run it on a local machine and to pass the output to some tools without having that "save to..." dialog all day long.

Is there a Python port of it available ? or do I have to fiddle with the very nasty output of js2py and still don't have the HTML buttons compiled properly.

I did some research but cant find one. Maybe I have to put a python web-server on an post all input there. I guess that is sadly the best solution currently.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but resource requests are off-topic as defined in the [help]. If it's totally local, yeah, running a minimal flask server and sending whatever data you want to send to it and writing to disk seems rather effortless to me, much easier than getting involved in a totally different port of blockly. If you shared a [mcve] of what you're trying to accomplish someone can show how to arrange this, I'm sure.

Comment: I want to save the generated code with a single click and maybe execute it with another button. But this is a very dirty solution. Better would be an IDE-Like project like the python IDE idle for example. Also accessing a list of project files might come in handy.